# How do I get pandas DataFrame from QThreadpool Worker?

Tags: python, pyside6

I am trying to have QThreadPool gather a lot of data all at once so I can speed up my program 'boot time.' Right now the program gets a bunch of DataFrames one after the other and then finally runs. The process of getting these DataFrames is usually a request.get or some wrapper around it and so QThreadPool is a good candidate to speed things up by getting a bunch of requests' DataFrames then printing them. However, I can not seem to get the DataFrame after the threadpool runs the thread. What am I doing wrong? To keep things simple, I just want to print the DataFrame.

My MVC code:

```
def get_data_1():
    # performs a get. I changed to just return a pre-made DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame({'value': [5,10,25,53], 'price': [2.24, 2.34, 5.22, 8.66]})

def get_data_2():
   # performs a get. I changed to just return a pre-made DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [10,20,75,103], 'price': [10.00, 5.29, 2.33, 8.77]})

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = Signal()  
    error = Signal(tuple)
    result = Signal(object)  # Might need to be Signal(DataFrame)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()


    @Slot()
    def run(self):

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data1 = None
        self.data2 = None
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.get_data() # should set data1 and data2. Do I put a wait / finish somewhere.
        
        def get_data(self):
            worker1 = Worker(get_data1)
            worker1.signals.result.connect(self.return_data1)
            self.threadpool.start(worker1)

            worker2 = Worker(get_data2)
            worker2.signals.result.connect(self.return_data2)
            self.threadpool.start(worker2)
            
            # does something go here
            print(self.data1)
            print(self.data2)

        def return_data1(self, df):
            self.data1 = df
        
        def return_data2(self, df):
            self.data2 = df
```

Is printing

```
<PySide6.QtCore.QMetaObject.Connection object at 0x000002CD3631C500>
<PySide6.QtCore.QMetaObject.Connection object at 0x000002CD3632A940>
```

when it should be giving me a DataFrame. However, printing df in `return_data` does give me the DataFrame. Note, the DataFrames are unrelated so I need not need to do anything complex in processing them; I am just trying to get them concurrently.

Comment: No, it should not give you the data frame. The `connect` of a signal returns the *connection*, not the result of calling the function connected to it. Think about it: if you have a button and connect it to a function that does something when the button is clicked, do you expect to get the result of that function when doing the connection and without ever clicking the button? Also, the return values of connected functions is *always* ignored, so if you want to do something when the thread ends, you have to do it in the connected function. Finally, threading does not "speed up" things.

Comment: 'doing stuff at the same time' is what I meant versus quicker.  It speeds it up in terms of I do not need to watch for each DataFrame to be processed. See my updated code based on what you are saying. However, when I try to use the data it is `None`

Comment: `waitForDone()` just not seem to be what I need.

Comment: I'm afraid that you don't understand how threading works, especially in Python; 1. concurrency is not parallelism, it's the ability to deal with *parts* of a processing by switching control between different contexts so that when a process (in the sense of processing a task, not that of multiprocessing) allows it another one can do part of its job; 2. Python limits the ability of multithreading due to the GIL, so if you have a long running task that is CPU bound you will get absolutely *no* benefit unless the task periodically releases control to other threads; 3. `wait()` is blocking for ->

Comment: I am guessing I want `asyncio` then, no? I am relatively new to parallelism. It is confusing, to say the least.

Comment: as they tell you, you are expecting a synchronous behavior of the threads but that is not useful in a GUI since you will get what you are trying to avoid: increase the boot time. Avoid the waitX methods as they will block the GUI thread and freeze it.

Comment: -> the calling thread (the thread in which `wait()` is called), so trying to use it to wait until the thread is finished makes using threading pointless. If with your "when I try to use the data it is `None`" you mean that `print(self.data1)` in `get_data()` results in `None` being printed, that's quite obvious: the connection is made in the main thread, so even assuming that the thread has already finished, the signal will not be processed until `get_data()` returns. I don't think that `asyncio` will change a lot (not to mention its complexity), and I believe that you're having a different ->

Comment: if you want parallelism then python is not the option. Asyncio does the same thing as Qt, it creates an eventloop, natively.

Comment: In the Qt context, threads are used to execute tasks in a new context to avoid blocking the main thread(GUI thread). It does not serve to speed up tasks.

Comment: -> problem: you are hoping to making startup of your program "faster", meaning that it shows as soon as possible without being blocked by the creation of the data. If that's the case, then that's not how threading will help you. Creation of that data will always require some time, sooner or later. What you may want is to provide a way to the user to realize that the program is "doing something", so your data will **always** be "empty" at startup, *but* you can connect the thread to functions that will eventually "finalize" the data within the UI, and eventually show some sort of "loading" ->

Comment: -> hint (such as a progress dialog) in the meantime. Also note that, unless the data creation allows to periodically release control to the main thread, using threading will *never* be useful. Since you're new to threading and parallelism, I'd suggest you to just ignore that aspect on your program at this time (just ensure that you show the "hint" above and eventually call `QApplication.processEvents()`) and in the meantime do some research and studying about those subjects, including the **important** differences between multithreading and multiprocessing, as general concepts *and* in Python.

Comment: Okay, I will do this!